# Python comma separated print changes function behavior

Tags: python, printing, delimiter

Although I've seen other questions on Python delimiters I haven't been able to find a question answering this so here goes. I'm writing a function that will recursively print an array backwards, and it appears to work just fine:

```
def print_array_backwards(array):
    if (len(array) == 1):
        print array[0],
        return
    print_array_backwards(array[1:])
    print array[0],

##########################################

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

print 'Array = ', x
print_array_backwards(x)
```

Will output:

```
Array =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
4 3 2 1 0 4 3 2 1 0
```

The problem is when I try to print the output of the print_array_backwards function in line with other text, like this:

```
print 'Array = ', x
print 'The array backwards is', print_array_backwards(x)
```

This will output:

```
Array =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
The array backwards is 4 3 2 1 0 4 3 2 1 0 None
```

My question is, where does this extra None value come from??

If I push the function output to the next line but leave the comma with the print statement like this:

```
print 'Array = ', x
print 'The array backwards is', 
print_array_backwards(x)
```

I obviously get the desired output:

```
Array =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
The array backwards is 4 3 2 1 0 4 3 2 1 0
```

Can anyone help me understand why leaving the function in the same line of the print statement causes the function to behave differently?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling a function that does not return anything explicitly. The default return value of such a function is `None`.

Simply don't print the return value of the function:

```
print 'Array = ', x
print 'The array backwards is',
print_array_backwards(x)
```

Comment: Duh! Thanks that makes total sense

Answer (score 1):

Change `print array[0]` to `return array[0]`. The `None` comes from the return value of `print_array_backwards()`, which since you specified nothing is `None`.

Comment: Tough this woudl workin the particular snippet, it would hardly be advisable: you'd end up witha funciton that would both print content to the stdout _and_ return a different value as part of the output.